# Unwanted ListView item Selection

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a `ListView` which has the method `setOnItemLongClickListener`. Whenever I am selecting the list items, Some list items in the `ListView` are automatically getting selected. Here's my code

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String present =listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                presentStudent.add(present);
            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what about the presentStudent?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal It is a arrayList. I am adding the selected students to this array. and then passing it to next Activity

Comment: You're returning `true` witch means that "regular" click will be called after  longClick. Did you implement `onClickListener` ? And why do you call `.getChildAt()` when you already have `View view` as an argument?

Comment: @Gotiasits No. I implemented only `onItemLongClickListener` . Help me where should i implement OnClickListener

Comment: just change the ItemLongClickListener with OnClickListener

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal How will i get the position of the clicked item.

Comment: You have an argument `View view` that is the item you clicked. Just cast it to correct type if needed.

Comment: @Gotiasits What I want is Mark the attendance on long Click and open student details on simple click,

Comment: @adityakumarsingh in that case use a OnClickListener inside OnLongClickListener.

Comment: The problem here as you states "some list items are automatically selected" means that you the Adapter is reusing an already selected view to display a new item, you need to store the state of selected in the object that adapter have and restore the state at the getView (also clearing the unselected state of a view)

Comment: Hope my answer on this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664207/check-a-list-view-item-from-adapter-when-long-clicked/48758888#48758888

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thank you for your response. but I didn't wanted to go that long way of maintaining my Adapter class. I have another question. How can I remove an item from the `arraylist` after deselecting the item. On the first click, I am adding that listitem to my `arraylist` and hilighting thati tem. What i want is to remove the item from arraylist on the second click that is when List item is not Hilighted.

Comment: The only easy way is to keep a field in the object to toggle between the selected state.