# Viewholder How to correctly update views

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I'm trying to update listview with dialog box. But when I'm input the quantity in dialog box then it will show to listview but when I scroll the listview other row will update also. I just want to update the row which I clicked.

Below is my adapter code.
Someone please help me. Thanks so much.

```
 public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView productid, productname, pcs, cs;
        ImageView dist;
    }

    public List<Product_List> parkingList;

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<Product_List> arrayList;

    private MyAppAdapter(List<Product_List> apps, Context context) {
        this.parkingList = apps;
        this.context = context;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Product_List>();
        arrayList.addAll(parkingList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return parkingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        final MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlist, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.productid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productid);
            viewHolder.productname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productname);
            viewHolder.pcs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pcs);
            viewHolder.cs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cs);
            viewHolder.dist = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.productid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getInvtID() + "");
        viewHolder.productname.setText(parkingList.get(position).getDescr() + "");

        final String a = viewHolder.productid.getText().toString();
        final String b = viewHolder.productname.getText().toString();

        if ( position % 2 == 0) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ECEAEA"));
        }

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(InventoryChecking1.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Inventory Checking");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.inventory);
                final TextView productids = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.productids);
                productids.setText(a);
                final TextView productdesc = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.productdesc);
                productdesc.setText(b);
                final EditText pcss = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pcss);
                final EditText css = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.css);
                final RadioButton btnyes = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnyes);
                final RadioButton btnno = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnno);
                btnno.setChecked(true);
                Button btnsave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
                btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewHolder.pcs.setText(pcss.getText().toString());

                        viewHolder.cs.setText(css.getText().toString());

                        if (btnyes.isChecked()) {
                            viewHolder.dist.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.dist.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: We are in age of RecycleView.. so just use it instead listview.

Comment: @dhams agree. using `RecycleView` is best approach

Comment: If you use `RecyclerView` you can use `notifyItemChanged()` of its adapter.

Comment: Never use views inside ListView to store values/strings as they get lost/recycle when you scroll. Yyou should store the values by yourself. Try to initialize arrays to store your cs(int), pcs(int) and dist(boolean). Then in getView(), use if-else to setText/setImageResource to those views. Inside OnClick(), you only set those values to corresponding position in the array and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). My answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552869/how-to-save-boolean-states-from-an-array-of-checkboxes-and-load-their-states-whe/48607776#48607776

Answer (score 1):

in your class where you call the adapter , 
set it as follow.

```
myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter();

imagegrid.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);

//imagegrid is a gridview where i need to set the adapter
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemsArrayList, InventoryChecking1.this);
                    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);

Comment: this is my adapter i cant add imagegrid

Comment: i meant that you have to replace that "imagegrid" with you list view object

Comment: it would be better if you add some images or further more clarification , so it would encourage someone to answer precisely

Answer (score 0):

You should call [**`notifyDataSetChanged ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

**DEMO**

```
tnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                       // Your work        
                       notifyDataSetChanged() 
                    }
                });
```

**FYI**

It will be a good approach if you use **`RecyclerView`** .

Comment: im tried but still same when i scroll the listview other row updated too but i just want the row which i clicked update. however thanks u try to help

Comment: @KaiJie You should add `setOnClickListener` section

Comment: added still same :(

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The question is to update only the row which he has clicked in listview. But listview does not provide method to only update an item.

Comment: @KaiJie use `RecyclerView `

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya ok accepted but my problem still havent solve maybe my coding have problem. it still same i can update but other row when i scroll the listview will update the same value too

Comment: @KaiJie Solved this yet?